# How to check if a mailserver uses SSL for IMAP communication (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, email, imap, mail-server

I have a service where I need the user to give me access to his email via IMAP.

I need the `user_name`, `password`, `address` and `port` from my user.

I also need to know if the IMAP connection uses SSL (`enable_ssl` can be `true` or `false`), and I would prefer not to ask my user. Because he probably don't know.

**Is it possible to make a query to the mailserver to see if it uses SSL?**

My solution so far has been try out both options. First I try to connect with SSL, and then - if this fails - I try to connect without SSL. But some mailservers strike out when I do this, maybe because the first failed connection is still open for some reason.

Here is my working (but clumsy) implementation.

```
require 'net/imap'
class ImapMailss
  def self.test_connection(address, port, enable_ssl, user_name, password)
    imap = Net::IMAP.new(address, port, enable_ssl)
    imap.login(user_name, password)
    flags = imap.list("", "*")
  end
end

enable_ssl == nil
# First I try to connect with SSL
begin
  true_test = ImapMailss.test_connection(address, port, true, user_name, password)
  if true_test.class.to_s == "Array" # If the mailserver allows me access I get an array of folders like e.g.: [#<struct Net::IMAP::MailboxList attr=[:Hasnochildren], delim="/", name="Feedback requests">, #<struct Net::IMAP::MailboxList attr=[:Hasnochildren], delim="/", name="INBOX">, #<struct Net::IMAP::MailboxList attr=[:Haschildren, :Noselect], delim="/", name="[Gmail]">, #<struct Net::IMAP::MailboxList attr=[:Hasnochildren, :Sent], delim="/", name="[Gmail]/Sent Mail">]
    enable_ssl   = true
  end
rescue => e
  true_error = e
end

# Then I try to connect without SSL
if enable_ssl == nil
  begin
    false_test = ImapMails.test_connection(address, port, false, user_name, password)
  if false_test.class.to_s == "Array"
    enable_ssl   = false
  end
  rescue => e
    false_error = e
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would the user know the port, but not whether it uses SSL?

Comment: He wouldn't, but I am trying to eliminate them one by one.

Comment: Also, if the server doesn't support SSL, the user probably shouldn't use it in the first place.

Comment: Not really relevant to my question...

Comment: If the port is 993, it is almost assuredly SSL.  If the port is 143, it almost assuredly not-SSL (but it may support STARTTLS, which you read from the CAPABILITY response).  If it otherwise, you should be able to try with SSL first, and fall back if it doesn't.   What do you mean by 'strike out'?

Comment: Hi @Max. Thanks for the comment. Unless I can be 100% sure I can't really rely on it, even though your assumptions on port 993 and 143 fits all the test cases I have been able to get my hands on. By "striking out" I mean that sometimes when I first try to connect with SSL to a 143 port I get the response `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol`, and when I then try to connect without I get a `connection closed` response. If I then wait 15 minutes or so I can connect without SSL.

Comment: Unknown protocol is the expected error when you connect SSL to the wrong port.  'connection closed' is very strange, perhaps the server is rate limiting you...  Are you just testing the one server?